# _in operator for custom check permissions for Hasura with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hasura

I am using v2.20.0 of Hasura Engine. I am using it with an SQL Server database.

I am defining custom checks for row-level permissions on tables and I see no `_in` operator. Whereas the _in operator has long been supported by Hasura in the case of Postgres.
[image]

Example: I have a session variable `x-hasura-department-ids` which contains an array. I want to enable row-level checks on tables such that a user is able to access a row if the DepartmentID in that row equals to any one of the values in the array contained in `x-hasura-department-ids`.

Am I missing something? Or is the `_in` operator not supported in the case of SQL Server?

Comment: Sql server does support arrays. You can use departmentId in (1,2,3) for similar function or perhaps a table type like "departmentId in (select id from @sometable)

Comment: I am talking specifically about the _in operator while defining Hasura Permissions settings, database integrated with Hasura is SQL Server. Please check my added screenshot above and let me know if you have a workaround for this.